# Getting SQL error for replace function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not to sure why this is happening and i've been trying to figure it out now for a while.

I've got the follow code

```
SELECT (MAX(replace(replace(replace(`sku`,'PA1-',''),'TES-',''),'BOX-',''))+1) AS maxValue FROM `product` WHERE `sku` LIKE '%PA1-TES-BOX%'
```

This was working a while back and nothing has changed code wise, I can only assume that a server changes has caused this to return the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ``` 'maxValue FROM ``product`` WHERE ``sku`` LIKE '%PA1-TES-BOX%' ```

Basically this SQL was built to find the first 3 section of this SKU code and return the ending + 1 so 002 would then return 003 to ensure unique sku codes.

Maybe the replace function has changed, i'm not entirely sure.

Does anyone have any ideas why this suddenly is throwing the error above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious syntax error.  But assuming the number is the last hyphenated item in the sku, the code could more easily be written as:

```
select (substring_index(sku, '-', -1) + 1) as maxvalue
. . .
```

One possibility for the syntax error is that an unprintable character crept in around the `as`.